# Specifying image dimensions like Gimp in ImageMagick

Tags: image, shell, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, gimp

I am editing an image in Gimp with dimensions and size specified as below.

[image]

How to use the same parameters in ImageMagick? (I tried something like below, but unable to get the desired output):

```
convert clipboard:image -crop 741x610+274+57 image.png
```

And how to copy this image back to clipboard?

Comment: You say you are *"unable to get the desired output"*. Can you please explain what do you get ***instead*** then?

Answer (score 0):

I don't currently have a Windows system around (the `clipboard:` thingie works only on Windows -- for Mac and Linux there are no equivalents within ImageMagick).

But I *think* it should work like this:

```
convert clipboard: -crop 741x610+274+57 +repage clipboard:
```

However, I'm wondering why you use the clipboard for output at all? *Why do you require to **write back** to the clipboard?* (There may be other means to achieve what you want...)

Comment: Copying back to clipboard is not the main priority but I am unable to get the exact image I am getting via gimp with those position and size. is the 741x610+274+57 right way? I am not getting the desired part of image with that.

Comment: @SteveErick: To successfully debug that you'd have to save the `clipboard:` image to file first. Then use (at least) `identify` to check for its dimensions (and if there is already any pre-offset involved). Also, ImageMagick starts counting rows and columns and pixels from index 0. I don't know what Gimp does (may use 1-based counting, not 0-based). However, I also assume a simple "off-by-one" error would have been discovered by you. IM starts from top left corner to calculate coordinates. AFAIK, Gimp does the same. So in theory, your command is correct (other than the potential "off-by-one").

Comment: Hi Kurt. I have worked out a way to use the clipboard on OSX with ImageMagick using `uuencode` as follows... `convert -size 200x500 xc:blue jpg:> >(uuencode -| pbcopy)` will write the JPEG nto the clipboard, and you can paste it back out like this... `convert jpg:< <(pbpaste | uudecode -p ) pasted.jpg`

Comment: Or equally, `convert -size 200x500 xc:blue jpg:- | uuencode -| pbcopy` followed by `pbpaste | uudecode -p | convert - pasted.jpg`

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Nice hack :)  I was pondering on coming up with s.th. similar... however, this hack is not *within* ImageMagick, but outside of it.